# hover animation on each element but not on the hovered element

Tags: jquery, hover, each

I have a very classic menu : when we click on a menu bttn, a text will appear nearby...

The structure :

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li class="menu-point">
        <span class="menu-text"></span>
        <a class="menu-bttn"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-point">
        <span class="menu-text"></span>
        <a class="menu-bttn"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-point">
        <span class="menu-text"></span>
        <a class="menu-bttn"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I do not know how to make visible the hidden element of ONLY the hovered menu point... my problem is the **EACH** element, and the fact that **NOT THE HOVERED** element is animated but the hidden element.

```
    $('#menu li a').bind({
        mouseenter: function() {
            $('.menu-text').animate({'opacity':1});
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            $('.menu-text').animate({'opacity':0});
        }
    });
```

Now, when i hover on a menu bttn, all menu texts are visible. How to make the menu text visible when its menu bttn is hovered ?

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/igorlaszlo/ht27090o/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't need jQuery for this. Here is a plain CSS solution:

```
#menu .menu-point:hover .menu-text {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/3tovgtjq/)

---

As for your question..

In order to refer to each element individually, use `$(this).prev('.menu-text')`.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/nkn755et/)

```
$(this).prev('.menu-text').animate({
    'opacity': 0
});
```

```
$('#menu li a').bind({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $(this).prev('.menu-text').animate({
            'opacity': 1
        });
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).prev('.menu-text').animate({
            'opacity': 0
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It would work but to complicate the thing, i have also another element nearby the text, an arrow... when i want to animate both elements (`$(this).prev('.menu-text,.arrow')`), on hover only the arrow is visible, and at active state only the text is visible... i would like both elements beeing visible...

Comment: I read just now that you say i do not need jquery for that... i tried of course what you suggested but if i make the animation on the menu-point hover, the animation will work even on the invisible text hover. I do not want it, i want that the hover works ONLY ON THE BUTTON hover; that is why i need jquery for that.

Answer (score 0):

try this

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ht27090o/1/)

```
    $('#menu li a').bind({
        mouseenter: function() {
            $(this).prev('.menu-text').animate({'opacity':1});
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            $(this).prev('.menu-text').animate({'opacity':0});
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you ! However Josh Crozier had this answer before you :)